# Are statistics calculated from Bootstrapped samples independent?

Tags: bootstrap, independence, resampling

I was wondering if someone could point me to some reference  stating the (in)dependence properties of statistics calculated from bootstrapped samples. In other words, are bootstrapped statistics (mean, median or anything else) independent, so that we can use non parametric tests on them (eg the Man-Whitney U)?

I did search on the internet, but didn't find anything relevant. Cant believe this has never been talked about before (or my googling skills failed me). Any pointers or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: The bootstrap resamples are independent, given the observed data. You would need to explain better what you want to do with hypothesis tests on them.

Comment: Thanks Kjetil! But its not intuitively clear why resamples (and the calculated statistics) are independent: since the same sampling units(rows of your data, for example) appear in different samples, independence is not obvious (to me).  Hence wanted to check with you -  do you have a reference or can you sketch a proof? The issue arose because I was wondering if we could use non-parametric tests like Man-Whitney U to compare any statistics  calculated from these resamples  between two groups (say smokers and non smokers)

Comment: Conditional on the original sample (observed data), probability of any bootstrap sample $b_i$ conditional on any other bootstrap sample $b_j$ is no different from the unconditional probability: $P(b_i|b_j,\text{orig.sample})=P(b_i | \text{orig.sample}), \forall \{i,j\}$.

Comment: Thanks Richard - Do you have a reference with a proof?

Comment: @xxxmsi, no, I constructed the argument using common sense only.

Comment: I doubt that this is proved in standard references, because it is seen as obvious. By the way, can you explain what you think you can gain by using non-parametric tests on bootstrapped data? Why not do the tests on the data directly? To get a useful answer, maybe tell us your real problem, on its own terms, not "translated to" statistics.